# html relative address to css style sheet not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, relative-path

I have a linux folder structure as follows for an apache server on a raspberry pi:

```
/var/www/html/index.html
/var/www/css/style.css
/var/www/php/someCode.php
```

index.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Introducing CSS Not Working</title>
 <link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"
 rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
 <h1>From Garden to Plate Not Working</h1>
 <p>A <i>potager</i> is a French term for an
 ornamental vegetable or kitchen garden ... </p>
 <h2>What to Plant</h2>
 <p>Plants are chosen as much for their functionality
 as for their color and form ... </p>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css is as follows:

```
body {
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;}
h1, h2 {
color: red;}
p {
color: #665544;}
```

The css isn't impacting the html.  Have you any idea why, I'm guessing something to do with the css link in `index.html`?

Comment: Look at the Network tab in your browser's Developer Tools and see how it's trying to resolve the path for your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that? (Chrome btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css file is out of root directory, I'd move it into the same directory where the index.html is or if you need css folder I would create them like this

```
/var/www/index.html
/var/www/css/style.css 
/var/www/php/someCode.php
```

Comment: The apache2 folder structure uses `var/www/html`.  To my organised brain this seems pointless to have html nested in www.  I want to move on with my life though, so have put `/css` and `/php` into `/var/www/html`.  It seems to work.